# Change File Permissions inside an Image File in Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, mkfs, udisks

I have an application (running in an IDE under my user account) that does the following:

1. It creates an empty file with ~1GiB size.
2. It calls `mkfs` on this file (btrfs currently, but may change in future).
3. It calls `udisksctl loop-setup` and `udisksctl mount` to mount it.

So far so good, but now I have the problem that I cannot create any files inside. To do this I would need to run chmod, which I can only do as root.

I do not want to run my application as root, because this could have huge security impacts.

In my opinion there should be a way to get the required permissions (without beeing root), because I have full access to the underlying image file nevertheless.

**Edit:** I found a solution that works at least. I'm creating a filesystem image with the according permissions set. Then I zip it and deploy it with my application. It is not perfect, but at least it works. If someone has a better idea, I would be very thankful to hear it.

**Edit2:** I do not need to chown or chmod anything, I just need to create, read, write and delete files and directories. Choosing a different filesystem is not an option.

Comment: Being able to mount an arbitrary image without restrictions already has huge security impacts. This sounds like an X-Y problem. Can you use CAP_CHOWN, CAP_FCHOWN and CAP_FSETID capabilities?

Comment: Nope, sorry. I don't want to change the configuration of the system in any way, because this makes the deployment of my application much harder.

Comment: In my opinion, the risk of having a security issue is minimal in the current configuration, because the application creates a new filesystem each time it boots (and deletes it afterwards).

Comment: In this case you are going to need to find or write tools to create the image rather than use the existing code in the kernel. btrfs is not the simplest choice! Linux initramfs uses cpio format and `mtools` allows you to manipulate vfat images.

Comment: That is very sad to hear. In that case, I would tend to pack an already prepared empty filesystem with my application (zipped of cause, to not waste space). Thanks anyway. If someone has a different idea, I would be very thankful to hear it.

Comment: @icarus It should be safe to mount with `nodev,nosuid`.

Comment: @icarus I think the question is, how do I create files inside of this new file-system?

Comment: Only a comment, as I can't remember well. I think the owner and mode of the mount-point has a big effect. I think it may be inherited by the root of the mounted file-system.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I agree that is what the question asks. I think this is an X-Y problem. As for the security aspects, nosuid and nodev help, but you also need to restrict where the mount can take place, you don't want me to be able to mount a new version of /etc. Checking that without race conditions is hard. There is a reasonable chance that he also wants to be able to chown files inside the new image. I think the best approach is to follow the example of the initramfs and generate a cpio file. cpio is simple enough to be easily generated by perl, python or even shell.

Comment: nosuid is not allowed by udisksctl, nodev does not help in any way (why should I have device special files in my image in the first place?). With udisksctl I am not able to decide where to mount the image file to (as far as I see it). It will always be in /run/media/<user>/<fs-uuid>. I think, that is the whole point of udisksctl: Preventing unsafe mount operations (such as mounting /etc). And no, I do not need to chown anything, I just need to create, read, write and delete files and directories. The solution I suggested above is not perfect, but at least it works.

Comment: Still: If anyone has an idea how to get it to work without deploying the image with the application, I would be thankful.

Comment: If you edit your question to focus on your goal, then I will vote it up. To try to get more attention. I don't think it is hard to do. But I don't have time to investigate.